# How to enable module rewrite in Apache configuration

Tags: magento, xampp

I'm trying to copy website made in Magento in my localhost and finished another steps:

- copied whole website via flash drive,

  import database from server,

  change parameters for database in local.xml (post root for user and
  empty field for password),

  clear cache in Magento var folder,

  change base_url value in database

When I try to open it in browser, Homepage looks ok, but any link in page give me Error 404 - Object not found. I can't access to admin panel. Anything what I type URL after localhost/nameOfMyProject, I get Error 404.

I have another Magento project in my localhost and they work correctly, but that I installed from fresh Magento installation and then add new themes for that.

Here is different situation. I need to add whole existing project from server in localhost. I can't add this website on same way, because developer who made it changed files into core section. Project is too big it's not possible at the moment to change that, so any way is to download whole project in localhost.

Does anyone has some suggestion what to do?

Comment: Do none of these projects have version control like SVN or Git? It's a lot easier and usually more successful using version control than copying files from a flash drive, did you get all the files off the flash drive? Even hidden files like htaccess?

Comment: Yes,I did get all the file and its not like SVN or Git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using XAMPP or WAMP as your web server, you may face a common problem that is the rewrite module (mod_rewrite) does not work properly. It is because the rewrite module is not enabled by default in Apache’s configuration settings. But you can enable it manually by following some simple steps:

1- Open apache’s configuration file using your favorite text editor. The configuration file is generally located at:

```
{apache_dir}/conf/httpd.conf
```

If you are using XAMPP or WAMP package then you will find the file at:

```
{xampp_dir}/apache/conf/httpd.conf
{wamp_dir}/apache/conf/httpd.conf
```

2- Search for the following string:#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so and uncomment it (remove the ‘`#`’ sign).

3- Now search for another string AllowOverride None and replace it by AllowOverride All

4- Finally save the changes, close your text editor and restart your apache server.